# Max-width on outer <td> not applying to inner span

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

When I hover over the table cell, it should show the Angular Bootstrap popover next to the text upon over. However, the 'span' element is still its full width.

```
 <td style="max-width: 50px; text-align: left; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis;"> 
    <span popover="I appeared on mouse enter!" popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover-placement="right" >This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. </span>
 </td>
```

[Screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g69rx.png)

How can I get the popover to display directly next to the text?

I tried putting a max width on the span itself, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: try with auto to popover-placement="auto"

Answer (score 0):

Think I found a solution:

1) Change the 'span' element to a 'div'

2) Add this styling to the div:

```
style="white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis;"
```